# gpflow install error: `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded'

Tags: python, git, tensorflow, setup.py, gpflow

I am trying to install GPflow following

https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/blob/master/README.md

I have  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I successfully installed tensorflow (I run a simple python script to test it and it worked).

I run from the shell

```
python setup.py develop
```

and it was giving me the error that was not finding the file setup.py. So I cloned the GPflow git repository in a local folder and then from that folder I executed

```
sudo python setup.py develop
```

(I needed to use sudo for access permission). But I got the following error:

```
  running develop
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 46, in <module>
        'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Artificial Intelligence']
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 971, in run_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 54, in finalize_options
        easy_install.finalize_options(self)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 333, in finalize_options
        self.index_url, search_path=self.shadow_path, hosts=hosts,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/package_index.py", line 296, in __init__
        Environment.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1055, in __init__
        self.scan(search_path)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1084, in scan
        for dist in find_distributions(item):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2048, in find_on_path
        for item in dists:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2034, in find_on_path
        path_item, entry, metadata, precedence=DEVELOP_DIST
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2463, in from_location
        py_version=py_version, platform=platform, **kw
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2442, in __init__
        self._version = safe_version(version)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1391, in safe_version
        return str(packaging.version.Version(version))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/version.py", line 230, in __init__
        self._version.local,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/version.py", line 353, in _cmpkey
        reversed(release),
    RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I also tried adding sys.setrecursionlimit(10000) in the setup.py file with no results.

Comment: Looks like your `python` executable is Python 2, but GPflow requires Python 3. You might need this instead: `sudo python3 setup.py develop`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reaching the recursing limit you can increase it with the following:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

Comment: I added these lines to my setup.py file but it did not worked out.